# MariaDB or MySQL Magento 2.4 "magento community edition open source"

Tags: magento2, database, mariadb

We are in the process of planning for an eCommerce project with Magento 2.4 "magento community edition open source" for building up the e-commerce project.

But we are really confused with which SQL Server to proceed MariaDB or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

For magento 2 you need

- MySQL 8.0 for on-premise installations
- MariaDB 10.4 for Magento Commerce Cloud projects

Magento is also compatible, but has not been tested and is not recommended, with MySQL 5.7.9, MariaDB 10.2, and Percona 5.7.

Magento only uses MySQL features compatible with MariaDB. MariaDB may not be compatible with all MySQL features, however; so be sure to research compatibility issues before using a feature in your Magento module.

Reindexing on MariaDB 10.4 takes more time compared to other MariaDB or MySQL versions
Thanks .

Comment: This answer should mention that it’s an exact copy/paste of the official documentation.

Comment: Downvoted as I don't feel this is particularly helpful in answering the question asked when it is just a straight copy and paste from Magento's documentation.